# importing string between two files

Tags: python, import

It seems I don't quite understand the import function. I would want to do it two way.

file1:

```
filename="tt.txt"
import file2
from file imort fileContent
```

file2:

```
from file1 import filename
fileContent=whats in the filename
```

That's approximately what I want to do, but it never gets the file name to file2.

Comment: There's your problem: `imort` isn't valid Python code, and neither is `whats in the filename`. Fix those and your syntax errors should go away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your first time with Python, and perhaps programming, so I'll advise you to ask questions on StackOverflow about a particular incident, providing as many details as possible, and to always include all code you've written.

Regardless,
Python's import statement is a utility that allows one module access to another. So for example, if I defined a file general.py as so:

```
def print_hello_world():
    print "Hello World Stack Overflow!"
```

and in any other file, included the code:

```
import general
general.print_hello_world
```

would give the output "Hello World Stack Overflow!"

Also, here's a reference guide to imports: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a circular import. file1 imports file2:

```
import file2
```

and file2 imports file1:

```
from file1 import filename
```

This is a no-no. file1 tells Python to import file2, which tells Python to import file1, which tells Python to import file2... etc.

What exactly happens when you run this code? Are you getting an `ImportError: cannot import name <blah>`? Is there any reason the code needs to be in two separate files, or could it be combined into one?